# unable to replace with jquery.extends with default values

Tags: jquery, call

I'm playing around with apply, bind and call methods on objects. Below I'm unable to replace `layout` with the public data say if I didn't pass in from the object I'm calling.

```
var data = [{
      "option": "com_social",
      "userId": localStorage.getItem("ckuser"),
      "layout": "getSample",
      "view": "conversations",
      "format": "json",
      "limit": 1
    }];
var Data = 'default';
function ajaxCall(opt){
    var opt = jQuery.extend({}, data, opt);
    var layout = opt[0]['layout'];
    this.Data = layout;

}

/***global variable & functions end***/

var list = {
           data : [{
              "option": "com_social",
              "userId": localStorage.getItem("ckuser"),
              "layout": "getConversations",
              "view": "conversations",
              "format": "json",
              "limit": 2
            }]
        }

ajaxCall.call (list, list.data);
console.log(list.Data);
```

if I don't pass in `"layout": "getConversations",` for object `list`, it says undefined. I understood I asked to use data from list object. But now I want to be able to use `jQuery.extend` to replace with default data if list object doesn't pass in the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery.extend` which is similar to `Object.assign` will extend an object but, not array.

In the below code:

`var opt = jQuery.extend({}, data, opt);` `data` is an array with no key. So, it's not working as you expect..

Try this instead:

`var opt = jQuery.extend({}, data[0], opt[0]);` instead of `var opt = jQuery.extend({}, data, opt);`

Comment: you're a beautiful angel! Thank you